# Ввод с клавиатуры с помощью Stream в массив, Java

Tags: java, input, java-stream

Подскажите, возможен ли ввод с клавиатуры в массив с помощью потоков Stream или класса Arrays?
Желательно одной строчкой

Answer (score 4):

в java 11 можно сделать примерно так

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Long> list = Stream.generate(scanner::nextLine) // Генерируем стрим, в котором значение будут те, что ввели в консоль. 
        .takeWhile(s -> !s.equals("exit"))           // Останавливаемся тогда, когда ввели `exit`
        .map(Long::valueOf)                          // Превращаем в Long ( ну или как вам надо там)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());               // Собираем в лист
System.out.println(list);
```

Если хотите собирать определенно число значений из терминала, то вместо `takeWhile` можно использовать `limit(X)`, где `X` - количество элементов

Comment: В EE8 так не сделаешь?

Comment: а с помощью стримовского метода foreach() это можно сделать как-то?

Comment: @Ivan в java8 можете воспользоваться библиотекой [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex). По поводу метода - что это за метод такой foreach?

Comment: @Andrew_Bystrov
Что-то наподобии такого: 

someList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
Для работы с массивом: 
Arrays.stream(someArray).forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: И что вы хотите этим методом сделать? Это терминальный метод,можете с помощью него вывести цифры на консоль

Comment: @Andrew_Bystrov, а ввести данные с клавиатуры, можно с помощью метода foreach?

Comment: Нет, с помощью метода foreach нельзя

Comment: @Andrew_Bystrov т.е метод foreach только например для умножения каждого элемента массива, и для вывода пригождается?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104896/discussion-between-andrew-bystrov-and-ivan).

Comment: @Andrew_Bystrov, а можно как-то использовать вместо Scanner'a BufferReader?.. пробую вводить "bf::readLine" и не хочет работать. Переменную bf BufferReader объявил ранее